# codHow to parse large JSON file of HuffingtonPost Pollster API

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to access:

choice: "Clinton",
value: "42.6",

and

choice: "Trump",
value: "37.7"

from the following API endpoint: http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/api/charts.json?topic=2016-president&state=us

I'm trying to get the values from the 1st JSON Object, but it returns multiple of them. Most of the JSON tutorials and questions I see are the standard JSON where I can just grab the value, but this one is tricking me and I cannot figure it out

I thought  pollObject[0].estimates[0].value and pollObject[0].estimates[1].value

would work bt it is not ... how do I grab those values in javascript? I'm trying to use them for a school project

My Code:

```
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');
var ENDPOINT = 'http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/api/charts.json?topic=2016-president&state=us';

function pollDataHelper() {

}

pollDataHelper.prototype.getPoll = function() {
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: ENDPOINT,
        json: true
    };
    console.log('hello333');
    return requestPromise(options);
}

pollDataHelper.prototype.formatePollData = function(pollObject) {
    var template = _.template("Currently Clinton is at ${clintonPoll} percent")
    + "Trump is at ${trumpPoll} percent";
    return template({
        clintonPoll: pollObject[0].estimates[0].value,
        trumpPoll: pollObject[0].estimates[1].value
    });
}

module.exports = pollDataHelper;
```

Comment: Try change pollObject[0].estimates[0].value = jsonVer[0].estimates[0].value

Comment: checking the `last_updated` property shows that the polls ain't ordered by date, actually the latest one including Trump and Clinton is at index 3 *(at the moment)*. Same for the estimates, you can't rely on any particular order, you have to check the `choice`-properties. Since you don't show how you call `formatePollData` I can't tell what you feed into this function, and therefore no idea what's wrong with your code. And "I thought ... would work, but it's not" is a really poor problem description.

Comment: Sidenote: why do I have to instantiate this helper if it ain't stateful? it's just a collection of 2 utility-methods.

Comment: I believe the poll order is set automatically, where Trump vs Clinton vs Johnson will always be the first because it is the one they use for their chart

Answer (score 0):

Try code

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"id":797,"title":"2016 General Election: Trump vs. Clinton vs. Johnson","slug":"2016-general-election-trump-vs-clinton-vs-johnson","topic":"2016-president","state":"US","short_title":"2016 President: Trump vs. Clinton vs. Johnson","election_date":"2016-11-08","poll_count":285,"last_updated":"2016-08-20T00:42:15.000Z","url":"http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2016-general-election-trump-vs-clinton-vs-johnson","estimates":[{"choice":"Clinton","value":"42.6","lead_confidence":100.0,"first_name":"Hillary","last_name":"Clinton","party":"Dem","incumbent":false},{"choice":"Trump","value":"35.7","lead_confidence":0.0,"first_name":"Donald","last_name":"Trump","party":"Rep","incumbent":false},{"choice":"Johnson","value":"8.7","lead_confidence":null,"first_name":"Gary","last_name":"Johnson","party":"Lib","incumbent":false},{"choice":"Other","value":"4.0","lead_confidence":null,"first_name":"","last_name":"Other","party":null,"incumbent":false}]},{"id":670,"title":"2016 General Election: Santorum vs. Clinton","slug":"2016-general-election-santorum-vs-clinton","topic":"2016-president","state":"US","short_title":"2016 President: Santorum vs. Clinton","election_date":"2016-11-08","poll_count":4,"last_updated":"2016-06-17T21:23:44.000Z","url":"http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2016-general-election-santorum-vs-clinton","estimates":[]},{"id":640,"title":"2016 General Election: Trump vs. Sanders","slug":"2016-general-election-trump-vs-sanders","topic":"2016-president","state":"US","short_title":"2016 President: Trump vs. Sanders","election_date":"2016-11-08","poll_count":93,"last_updated":"2016-08-20T00:37:41.000Z","url":"http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2016-general-election-trump-vs-sanders","estimates":[{"choice":"Sanders","value":"49.9","lead_confidence":100.0,"first_name":"Bernie","last_name":"Sanders","party":"Dem","incumbent":false},{"choice":"Trump","value":"38.9","lead_confidence":0.0,"first_name":"Donald","last_name":"Trump","party":"Rep","incumbent":false},{"choice":"Other","value":"3.9","lead_confidence":null,"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"party":"N/A","incumbent":false}]},{"id":624,"title":"2016 General Election: Trump vs. Clinton","slug":"2016-general-election-trump-vs-clinton","topic":"2016-president","state":"US","short_title":"2016 President: Trump vs. Clinton","election_date":"2016-11-08","poll_count":285,"last_updated":"2016-08-20T01:39:11.000Z","url":"http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2016-general-election-trump-vs-clinton","estimates":[{"choice":"Clinton","value":"47.6","lead_confidence":100.0,"first_name":"Hillary","last_name":"Clinton","party":"Dem","incumbent":false},{"choice":"Trump","value":"39.5","lead_confidence":0.0,"first_name":"Donald","last_name":"Trump","party":"Rep","incumbent":false},{"choice":"Other","value":5.8,"lead_confidence":null,"first_name":"","last_name":"Other","party":null,"incumbent":false}]}]');
console.log(data[0].estimates[0].value);
console.log(data[0].estimates[1].value);
```

if you want get all data of estimates. You should using loop

Comment: I am getting the JSON live as a request though so I cannot just have it like that

Comment: I took out the Jsonver becasue it also does not work. when I try to get the estimate[0].value It's returning undefined even though when I call the 1st function I can get the entire json

Comment: pollObject only is string should it undefined. You must using var my_data = JSON.parse(pollObject) and get value my_data

Comment: I don't think thats true I am able to print the first function in its entirety which grabs the entire json object

Answer (score 0):

Try my code. It is run success.

```
var request = require("request");
request({
      uri: "http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/api/charts.json?topic=2016-president&state=us",

}, function(error, response, body) {
     // console.log(response.body[0].estimates[0].value); ==> undefined
    var results = JSON.parse(response.body);
    console.log(results[0].estimates[0].value);  // ==> value = 42.6
    console.log(results[0].estimates[1].value);  // ==> value = 35.7
});
```